# Is there a way to have multiple FKs mapped with 1 virtual field in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class Post
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? BlogId { get; set; }
    public Guid? BlogUuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Uuid { get; set; }
    public vitual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

`OnModelCreating` for `Post`:

```
builder.HasOne(e => e.Blog)
       .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(po => po.BlogUuid)
       .HasPrincipalKey(bl => bl.Uuid);

builder.HasOne(e => e.Blog)
       .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(po => po.BlogId)
       .HasPrincipalKey(bl => bl.Id);
```

With above we are able to define relationships among tables but when we do something like

```
var blog = new Blog { Id = 1, Uuid = Guid.New(), Name: "Test Blog" }
var post = _context.Posts.First();
post.Blog = blog;
```

Now, `post.BlogId` is set to 1, `post.Blog` is set to the blog object,
but `post.BlogUuid` is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Why??? If an Id uniquely identifies a Blog, why would you need the UUID? If you happen to want all posts for a blog given a blog UUID you can always query that via the navigation property:

Either:

```
var posts = context.Blogs
    .Where(x => x.Uuid == uuid)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Posts)
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var posts = context.Posts
    .Where(x => x.Blog.Uuid == uuid)
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively you can get rid of the Id entirely and just use the UUID as the PK & FK.

The main issue with using UUIDs as keys is their random-ish nature and the implications this has on things like fragmentation on index tables which is why people recommend using things like Long or Int for PK/FK. The issue with searching by the UUID as an alternative to the numeric ID is that you're either creating an index and dealing with that exact same fragmentation issue, or you are doing a non-indexed table scan. So it is better that if you're going to be referencing Posts by Blog and using a numeric Blog ID, use that numeric ID as much as possible.

**Edit:** From the comments it reads like when creating a Post you would have a Post DTO for the post-related data, and the Blog UUID and want to insert the post associated to the matching blog.

There are a couple of ways to approach this considering performance and data integrity. Considerations with any API call passing FKs or identifying criteria should include "Are these IDs actually valid?". They should also include any integrity checks such as things like repeats such as users double-clicking Submit buttons or using Back/Next to re-submit,etc. At the end of the day, data coming from a client should not be trusted, so to some degree we need to weigh up performance and ensuring the data is complete and correct.

If there are expected to be a reasonable number of Posts within a blog (hundreds or less for example) then one option would be:

```
var blog = context.Blogs
    .Include(x => x.Posts)
    .Single(x => x.Uuid == postDTO.BlogUuid);

var post = Mapper.Map<Post>(postDTO);
blog.Posts.Add(post);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Ahead of this would be validating the postDTO to ensure it is complete and acceptable. The above code would throw if we are given an invalid blog Uuid. We might also want to check the existing posts for a possible duplicate.

In a situation where blogs might have hundreds or thousands of posts but we still want to be able to check for reasonable duplicates then we can consider going to the posts:

```
var recentCutoffDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14);
var recentPosts = context.Posts
    .Include(x => x.Blog)
    .Where(x => x.Blog.Uuid == postDTO.BlogUuid
        && x.CreatedDateTime >= recentCutoffDateTime)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDateTime)
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();
var blog = recentPosts.FirstOrDefault()?.Blog 
    ?? context.Blogs.Single(x => x.Uuid == postDTO.BlogUuid);

// TODO: use the recent posts to validate for duplicates etc.

var post = Mapper.Map<Post>(postDTO);
post.Blog = blog;
context.Posts.Add(post);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This gets any posts over the last 14 days and takes the most recent 5 for comparisons. It's possible the blog doesn't have any posts, or any in the last 14 days so if don't get at least one post we will need to go to the DbContext to get the Blog. We can use the posts retrieved to check for a duplicate or other validation/references. Obviously the window of posts pulled back can be tightened or widened, this was just an example of trimming down possible sets using the query so we can get useful data back without the overhead of reading everything.

For performance, if you don't need to rely on the database to check for duplicates and want to minimize round trips:

```
var blog = context.Blogs.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Uuid == postDTO.BlogUuid);
bool stubUsed = false;
if (blog == null)
{
    var blogId = context.Blogs
        .Where(x => x.Uuid == postDTO.BlogUuid)
        .Select(x => x.Id)
        .Single();
    stubUsed = true;
    blog = new Blog { Id = blogId };
    context.Attach(blog);
}

var post = Mapper.Map<Post>(postDTO);
post.Blog = blog;
context.Posts.Add(post);
context.SaveChanges();
if (stubUsed)
    context.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

This solution checks the local DbContext cache assuming you are using something like an injected DbContext. If the DbContext is a locally scoped DbContext (such as with a `using` block) then this could be skipped as no instances might already be tracked in cache. If there is a blog in the cache we use it, otherwise we fetch just the Blog ID from the database. (rather than returning an entire Blog) We use that ID to create a stub Blog that we can attach to the DbContext which will now treat it like an existing record, so we can create the Post and associate it to the Blog before saving.

The code around the "stubUsed" flag is in the case of an injected DbContext, that stub Blog will be in the cache and later code asking for a Blog from the DbContext would be given the tracked Stub which is useless and incomplete. So if we added a stub we want to detach it after saving our Post so the DbContext goes to the database to retrieve the real blog if asked.

If we are scoping the DbContext with a `using` block then the last example can be streamlined:

```
using (var context = AppContextFactory.Create())
{
    var blogId = context.Blogs
        .Where(x => x.Uuid == postDTO.BlogUuid)
        .Select(x => x.Id)
        .Single();
    blog = new Blog { Id = blogId };
    context.Attach(blog);

    var post = Mapper.Map<Post>(postDTO);
    post.Blog = blog;
    context.Posts.Add(post);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

No need to worry about stub detaching or local cache checks. The above code uses an injected DbContext factory to handle DbContext instance initialization.

This should hopefully give you some ideas around handling your scenario.

Comment: So we have UUIDs for external clients and long Ids for all internal clients, that way we expect to have faster processing at least for internal services, the problem I'm facing is in maintaining both simultaneously. We cannot expose long Id's to external clients.

Let's say we get a request from external client to fetch all Posts from a Blog with UUID (some random Guid), now we plan to go to Blog table and get long Id for that particular Blog then use that long Id in Post table to find all corresponding Posts.

Comment: Since you have the navigation properties between Blog and Posts you can just use either of the above examples to fetch the posts given the UUID. EF will only load the associated Post entities if that is what is desired. You don't need to explicitly find the BlogId and use that to fetch the Posts, EF navigation properties let EF build a suitable query with the relationship.

Comment: Thanks, this seems reasonable enough.
However, the problem we face is, when we want to add a new Post and our Post object doesn't have Blog Id (Guid), and since we are not exposing Blog Id (long) we have to make an API with accepts 2 parameters, Post Obj and Blog Id, which we are trying to avoid.
Is there any way you think we can handle this.?

We use PostDto for inbounds and outbounds and it is exactly similar to Post except virtual fields.

Comment: I have expanded on the answer to provide a few examples for options on how to handle scenarios like that which should give your some ideas on how to approach it efficiently.